# Get drawable from 3d gallery an pass it to other activity into an imageview saving into sharedpreferences

Tags: sharedpreferences, adapter, gallery, avatar

I'm making an app. I have a 3d gallery with an imageAdapter, galleryView, gallery3dActivity and the mainactivity.

ImageAdapter:

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter 
{
private ImageView[] mImages;

private Context mContext;
public List<Map<String, Object>> list;


public Integer[] imgs = { R.drawable.cat, R.drawable.dog, R.drawable.bird,
    R.drawable.chicken, R.drawable.cow, R.drawable.rabbit, R.drawable.pig, 
    R.drawable.sheep, R.drawable.donkey, R.drawable.deer, R.drawable.fox,
    R.drawable.helephant, R.drawable.tiger, R.drawable.leopard, R.drawable.lion, 
    R.drawable.monquey, R.drawable.owl, R.drawable.panda, R.drawable.pinguin, R.drawable.zebra,};
public String[] titles = { "The Cat.", "The Dog", "The Bird", "The Chicken", "The Cow", "The Rabbit", 
"The Pig", "The Sheep", "The Donkey", "The Deer","The Fox", "The Helephant", "The Tiger", "The Leopard", 
"The Lion", "The Monquey", "The Owl", "The Panda", "The Pinguin", "The Zebra"};

public ImageAdapter(Context c) 
{
    this.mContext = c;
    list = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();
    for (int i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
        HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        map.put("image", imgs[i]);
        list.add(map);
    }
    mImages = new ImageView[list.size()];
}

public boolean createReflectedImages() 
{
    final int reflectionGap = 0;
    final int Height = 350;
    int index = 0;
    for (Map<String, Object> map : list) {
        Integer id = (Integer) map.get("image");

        Bitmap originalImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), id);   
        int width = originalImage.getWidth();
        int height = originalImage.getHeight();
        float scale = Height / (float)height;

        Matrix sMatrix = new Matrix();
        sMatrix.postScale(scale, scale);
        Bitmap miniBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(originalImage, 0, 0,
                originalImage.getWidth(), originalImage.getHeight(), sMatrix, true);

        originalImage.recycle();

        int mwidth = miniBitmap.getWidth();
        int mheight = miniBitmap.getHeight();
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.preScale(1, -1);
        Bitmap reflectionImage = Bitmap.createBitmap(miniBitmap, 0, mheight/2, mwidth, mheight/2, matrix, false);
        Bitmap bitmapWithReflection = Bitmap.createBitmap(mwidth, (mheight + mheight / 2), Config.ARGB_8888);

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmapWithReflection);
        canvas.drawBitmap(miniBitmap, 0, 0, null);
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        canvas.drawRect(0, mheight, mwidth, mheight + reflectionGap, paint);
        canvas.drawBitmap(reflectionImage, 0, mheight + reflectionGap, null);

        paint = new Paint();
        LinearGradient shader = new LinearGradient(0, miniBitmap.getHeight(), 0, bitmapWithReflection.getHeight()
                + reflectionGap, 0x70ffffff, 0x00ffffff, TileMode.CLAMP);
        paint.setShader(shader);
        paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.DST_IN));
        canvas.drawRect(0, mheight, mwidth, bitmapWithReflection.getHeight() + reflectionGap, paint);

        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmapWithReflection);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GalleryView.LayoutParams((int)(width * scale),
                (int)(mheight * 3 / 2.0 + reflectionGap)));
        imageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);
        mImages[index++] = imageView;
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return imgs.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return mImages[position];
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    return mImages[position];
}

public float getScale(boolean focused, int offset) {
    return Math.max(0, 1.0f / (float) Math.pow(2, Math.abs(offset)));
}

}
```

GalleryView:

```
public class GalleryView extends Gallery 
{
private Camera mCamera = new Camera();
private int mMaxRotationAngle = 45; 
private int mMaxZoom = -120;
private int mCoveflowCenter;

public GalleryView(Context context) 
{
    super(context);
    this.setStaticTransformationsEnabled(true);
}

public GalleryView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) 
{
    super(context, attrs);
    this.setStaticTransformationsEnabled(true);
}

public GalleryView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) 
{
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    this.setStaticTransformationsEnabled(true);
}

public int getMaxRotationAngle() 
{
    return mMaxRotationAngle;
}

public void setMaxRotationAngle(int maxRotationAngle) 
{
    mMaxRotationAngle = maxRotationAngle;
}

public int getMaxZoom() 
{
    return mMaxZoom;
}

public void setMaxZoom(int maxZoom) 
{
    mMaxZoom = maxZoom;
}

private int getCenterOfCoverflow() 
{
    return (getWidth() - getPaddingLeft() - getPaddingRight()) / 2 + getPaddingLeft();
}

private static int getCenterOfView(View view) {
    return view.getLeft() + view.getWidth() / 2;
}

@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) 
{
    mCoveflowCenter = getCenterOfCoverflow();
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
} 

@Override
protected boolean getChildStaticTransformation(View child, Transformation trans) 
{
    final int childCenter = getCenterOfView(child);
    final int childWidth = child.getWidth();
    int rotationAngle = 0;

    trans.clear();
    trans.setTransformationType(Transformation.TYPE_BOTH);

    if (childCenter == mCoveflowCenter) 
    {
        transformImageBitmap((ImageView) child, trans, 0);  
    } 
    else 
    {
        rotationAngle = (int) ( ( (float) (mCoveflowCenter - childCenter) / childWidth ) * mMaxRotationAngle );
        if (Math.abs(rotationAngle) > mMaxRotationAngle) 
        {
            rotationAngle = (rotationAngle < 0) ? -mMaxRotationAngle : mMaxRotationAngle;
        }
        transformImageBitmap((ImageView) child, trans, rotationAngle);
    }

    return true;
}

private void transformImageBitmap(ImageView child, Transformation trans, int rotationAngle) 
{
    mCamera.save();

    final Matrix imageMatrix = trans.getMatrix();
    final int imageHeight = child.getLayoutParams().height;
    final int imageWidth = child.getLayoutParams().width;
    final int rotation = Math.abs(rotationAngle);

    mCamera.translate(0.0f, 0.0f, -20.0f);

    // As the angle of the view gets less, zoom in
    if (rotation < mMaxRotationAngle)
    {
        float zoomAmount = (float) (mMaxZoom + (rotation * 1.0));
        mCamera.translate(0.0f, 0.0f, zoomAmount);
    }

    mCamera.rotateY(rotationAngle);
    mCamera.getMatrix(imageMatrix);
    imageMatrix.preTranslate(-(imageWidth / 2), -(imageHeight / 2));
    imageMatrix.postTranslate((imageWidth / 2), (imageHeight / 2));

    mCamera.restore();
}
}
```

Gallery3DActivity:

```
public class Gallery3DActivity extends Activity {

private TextView tvTitle;   
private GalleryView gallery;    
private ImageAdapter adapter;
private ImageView Avatar;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.grallery_layout);

    initRes();
}

private void initRes(){
    tvTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
    gallery = (GalleryView) findViewById(R.id.mygallery);
    Avatar = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageAvatar);
    adapter = new ImageAdapter(this);   
    adapter.createReflectedImages();
    gallery.setAdapter(adapter);

    gallery.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            tvTitle.setText(adapter.titles[position]);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        }
    });

    gallery.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Intent i = new Intent(Gallery3DActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            int grallery_layout = 0;
            Avatar.setImageResource(R.layout.grallery_layout);
            startActivity(i);
            Toast.makeText(Gallery3DActivity.this, "img " + (position+1) + " selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
}
```

In the `gallery.setOnItemClickListener` I try to get the drawable and show it on the main activity in the imageview with *id imageAvatar* but it does't work. I tried a lot of methods without luck. Grid type doesn't work, after I wanted to save the imageview new drawable using shared preferences.

Answer (score 0):

here is the solution i got working...
My intent of gallery3dActivity is:

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View  view, int position, long id) {
int selectedId = imgs[position]; 
Intent intent = new Intent(Gallery3DActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("imageId", selectedId);
startActivity(intent);
}
```

this will send the selected drawable inside the intent to my main activity,
in the main activity i receive the intent and set it on the imageview:

```
Intent avatar = getIntent(); 
int imageId = avatar.getIntExtra("imageId", -0); 
// -0 would be a default value
// -1 will crash with a missing resource

if (getIntent().getExtras() != null)
{Avatar.setImageResource(imageId);
savedAvatar.setImageResource(imageId);
update.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
else
{Avatar.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
}
```

i have a button with id update on my main activity, that onclick calls setProfilePhoto:

```
public void setProfilePhoto(View view){
//code image to string
savedAvatar.buildDrawingCache();
Bitmap bitmap = savedAvatar.getDrawingCache();
ByteArrayOutputStream stream=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
byte[] image=stream.toByteArray();
String img_str = Base64.encodeToString(image, 0);

//decode string to image
String base=img_str;
byte[] imageAsBytes = Base64.decode(base.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);
Avatar.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageAsBytes, 0, imageAsBytes.length) );

//save in sharedpreferences
SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("myprefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
editor.putString("userphoto",img_str);
editor.commit();
update.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

this will get the imageview drawingcache converting it bitmao them to string, the string back to image to be able to display it on the imageview and i save the string in the sharedpreferences.
After i retrieve the image back on the oncreate method calling 2 methods:

```
checkFirstLogin();
prepareForm();
```

wich are like this:

```
private void prepareForm() {
SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("myprefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
// If value for key not exist then return second param value - In this case "..."
String img_str=preferences.getString("userphoto", "");
if (!img_str.equals("")){
//decode string to image
String base=img_str;
byte[] imageAsBytes = Base64.decode(base.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);
        Avatar.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageAsBytes, 0, imageAsBytes.length) );
        savedAvatar.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageAsBytes, 0, imageAsBytes.length) );
    }
}

private void checkFirstLogin() {
    SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("myprefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
    // If value for key not exist then return second param value - In this case true
    if (preferences.getBoolean("firstLogin", true)) {
        initProfile();
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("firstLogin", false);
        editor.commit();
    }
}
```

and finaly inside the method chechfirstlogin i call initProfile method:

```
private void initProfile() {
SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("myprefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
editor.commit();
}
```

that will call sharedpreferences.

thats it, it works perfectly the code, i hope this can help someone, sorry for making such a hard question and make such big answer. have a good day.